# How did the people of Marley steal 7 of the 9 original titans?

Tags: attack-on-titan

The story of Attack on Titan says the Eldian Empire grew unstable due to internal conflicts between the families with the power of the Titans, and collapsed during the Great Titan War a century ago, and that Eldia lost 7 of the 9 Titans to the nation of Marley.

How did the people of Marley steal 7 of the 9 original titans?

Comment: To be honest, it's still unknown in the manga. It can either be because some titian shifters could have joind with Marley,  or Marley was able to weaken some of the titan shifters and used Yrmi's people that joind Marley to take over the powers. People are still waiting for that answer in the manga

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it was 8
not 7.
As simple as I can say
when king fritz decided to go and live on the paradise island. He only took the **founding** titan with him. And the other 8 titans remained on the mainland.

> 7 of them in the hand of Marley and the other one (Warhammer titan) in the Tybur family.

Answer (score 2):

There is no official answer in the manga, but I can speculate that they pulled a Riener and simply bit the nape of the Titan, taking their powers (and life). They might have waited 13 years, or just killed them outright to separate the powers. There could have been constant attacks and threats to the titan shifters, so this also might explain the reason the Ackerman family came to be. We know one thing though, King Riess said he was horrified at the atrocities of his ancestors (or something along those lines). There was probably a ton of backstabbing that, over time, enabled Marley to eventually acquire seven out of the nine titans.